# How to use pandas.core.window.Window.mean function?

Tags: python, pandas, window

I suppose the function should be used like

```
    pd.Window_mean(df.Returns, 5)
```

but it raises AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'Window'. What should I do to make it work?
The documentation of the function I'm referring to is here https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.window.Window.mean.html

Comment: The function is deprecated as of 0.18. Use `resample.mean` instead.

Comment: Try  `df.Returns.rolling(window=5).mean()`  
[docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you need to use `rolling mean`, as the `window_mean` is deprecated i.e

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'B': [0, 1, 2, 2, 4,8, 5, 4, 2, 4,0, 1, 1,6, 4]})
df['B'].rolling(window=5).mean()

0     NaN
1     NaN
2     NaN
3     NaN
4     1.8
5     3.4
6     4.2
7     4.6
8     4.6
9     4.6
10    3.0
11    2.2
12    1.6
13    2.4
14    2.4
Name: B, dtype: float64
```